# One ObjectDataSource for two ASP.NET controls

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

Does anyone know how many trips to the database will be made on Select if I use one ObjectDataSource for two ASP.NET controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two trips
http://forums.asp.net/t/1449289.aspx

you can cach the data 
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/caching-data-with-the-objectdatasource-vb

or make a call to the object

```
List<T> foo = yourObject.GetSource();
control1.DataSource = foo;
control2.DataSource = foo;
```

Comment: Thats what I thought.  Thanks for the suggesting how to share the data between the two objects.  I'll give it a try.